# Kaspersky Mobile: disable lock

Tags: lock-screens, antivirus, anti-theft

I have Kaspersky Mobile installed. Today I had to reinstall it after installing a new rom. Now whenever I turn on the phone, I have to enter the kaspersky unlock code, which is different from the sim card lock code. Before I had the lockcode disabled, and I could use the phone without having to enther any code. I would like to disable the lock code, but can't find the option in the Kaspersky app. I've searched in the system settings, but no luck.

Can you tell me where I can set this option?

Phone info: Samsung Galaxy S2 I9100, Android JB 4.2.2, Avatarrom

Comment: OP: What Device? What ROM? What Android version? Three vital questions omitted...

Comment: Are you sure it's even Kaspersky doing that? Lock settings are usually done by Android itself. Have you checked in *Settings* there?

Comment: @t0mm13b, I updated the question.

Comment: @Izzy, I have to enter the kaspersky code, not the simlock code. So that's enough proof that it's the Kaspersky app.

Comment: Hmmm... Try wiping the data/cache from recovery - *do a  backup before hand in case!*

Comment: @rxt thanks for clarification! I couldn't see that from your question – maybe you want to include it there? As you can see by geffchang's answer, I'm not the only one having this misunderstood :)

Comment: @Izzy - I already did include it in my question!

Comment: Thanks (confirmed: you did so 8 minutes after my comment – probably we were writing at the same time ;)

Comment: @t0mm13b, I tried to restore a backup with Titanium Backup, but that didn't help. Great tool though - it has saved me much time while installing new roms!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it. This is what I did:

- System settings > Security > Device managers
- Disable Kaspersky as device manager
- System settings > Screen lock: swipe (or what you want)
- Enable Kaspersky as device manager

Now I can unlock the phone with one swipe. I use App Protector to lock certain apps plus system settings with a different code.

NB: the above names (like device manager) may not be 100% accurate as I'm not using an English version of Android...

Comment: My English Android device calls it a Device Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings > Screen lock> None

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear on Kaspersky but on SOME phone/android version, the K pin code/swipe... is overriding the one of the phone.
In other words, go to your phone settings, not K, and disable screen locking!
K lock will be disabled, phone one also of course.

At this point you can either recreate one of the phone or one in K, which of course will override the phone one if it was already the case.

This concern only the screen lock, for paranoiac you can have 2 app lock at the same time.